# UTF8 correct string length with vardump

Tags: php, utf-8, string-length, var-dump

How can I make var_dump like output from an array that manages string characters length well, that is the same counts with and without accents?

```
/var/www/test.php:4:
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'qwertzuiop' (length=10)
  1 => string 'qwértzúíóp' (length=14)
```

Comment: Did you actually *try anything*? Start with a loop... and then try to make something that matches what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `mb_strlen()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

This should return a length of 10 for `'qwértzúíóp'`.

`var_dump()` will always return a length of 14 bytes for `'qwértzúíóp'` because that is the actual size.

Comment: That's fine, but I do not need to be value, but must be a formatted output. Like var_dump: key, value, length and formatted for multi-level arrays.

Comment: Have you looked for `dump_var()` alternatives? See: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/10/smart-alternative-phps-var_dump-function There are many.